# Problem with TexWorks and misleading error

Tags: ubuntu, texworks

I have installed TexWorks via Ubuntu Software launcer.

When I make a mistake in an equation I get an error but when corrected and run again I get the error
! Undefined control sequence.
l.36 \newla

that seems to be totally unrelated related to the original code and I when I search for newla in the .tex file I can find[image] nothing.

This particular section of code is shown in the attachment.

As well, it seems to create an empty file called
MATH 421.synctex(busy)

To proceed Ihave to physically delete the .aux, .log, .syntext.gz and .synctex(busy) files before the corrected code works.

I have tried removing TexWorks and reinstalling to no avail. Any suggestions welcome. While having to delete the files and then run TexWorks again isn't the end  of the world, it is annoying.

Comment: Just for your information.... Some times we have to clean the aux (and similar) files... Try to delete the `.aux` file and recompile... Of course we need info about the compilation command you have set in the options of TeXWorks....

Comment: you seem to kill the application when you get an error. Don't klick on the x in some windows in this case, instead type x on your keyboard and then hit enter.

Comment: look at your `.aux` file it was corrupted in a previous run (probably as you quit the process on an error rather than letting tex exit) so the file has `\newla` instead of `\newlanguage` and therefore the error that you show is correct. Delete the `aux` file and the error will go.

Comment: Your image shows that the error is on line 36 of MATH421.aux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log file shown in your image shows that line 36 of your `.aux` file, `MATH421.aux` does in fact have the undefined command `\newla` that generates the error that you show.

So the error message is not misleading, it is pinpointing a genuine error.

Deleting the `.aux` file will clear the error.

The underlying question is why the `.aux` file has `\newla`. that is harder to answer without a test file, but TeX would have been writing `\newlanguage` but the process ended without completing the write. Usually (but not always) that is because the user has killed the process (eg by clicking the X in a GUI window) so the operating system terminates the tex process while it is writing the `.aux` file, leaving it corrupted.

If TeX is allowed to terminate gracefully (eg by typing `x` to any error prompt) then any file writing will be completed and files flushed before the process ends, so corruption of the auxiliary file is less likely.

Comment: Thanks to everyone pointing out my mistake regarding the error and for the comments